# GCM demo sample works on emulator but not on device

Tags: android, android-c2dm, google-cloud-messaging

I'm trying to run GCM demo semple. It works on emulator and I can recive messages from servers. But on device it try to register on servers and after 5 attempts fails to register.
Any ides?

Comment: Put some more details or the part of the code.

Comment: That is standard gcm sample provided by google. I just follow the steps of official guide. For server side i use Tomcat 6. I use API key from API console.
Just I'm very confused that this works on emulator but not on real device.